# Pyqt pass object name or argument when QLabel is clicked (mousePressEvent)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have various QLabels in my GUI and I want to highlight the QLabel when the user clicks it. I can't work out how to pass the object via the function, or get the object via the event. I can make a specific function for each QLabel, but there is approximately 20 of them so it wouldn't be very concise/elegant.

For example:

```
self.sf0.mousePressEvent = self.highlight_frame

def highlight_frame(self, event):
        event.setStyleSheet("border: 3px solid blue;")
```

Gets the QMouseEvent but can't find the object with that.

```
self.sf0.mousePressEvent = (lambda: self.highlight_frame("sf0"))

def highlight_frame(self, frame_name):
        attribute = getattr(self, frame_name)
        attribute.setStyleSheet("border: 3px solid blue;")
```

gives error "TypeError: Ui.**init**..() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

or with sender

```
self.sf0.mousePressEvent = self.highlight_frame

def highlight_frame(self, frame_name):
        sender = self.sender()
        sender.setStyleSheet("border: 3px solid blue;")
```

gives error "    sender.setStyleSheet("border: 3px solid blue;")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setStyleSheet"

I've seen various answers using functools but this appears to be deprecated?

Thanks in advance,
Sean

Comment: Just don't do any of the above. Use an event filter or subclasses with the `mousePressEvent` override. Do some research on those aspects as there are dozens of related posts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning function to `mousePressEvent` connect the it's signal to `highlight_frame` function by `self.sf0.mousePressEvent.connect(self.highlight_frame)` and don't forget to check what parameters are sent by `self.sf0.mousePressEvent` and accept those parameters in your connected function

Comment: But `mousePressEvent` is a *event-handler*, not a signal, so your suggestion makes no sense (in fact, your code will just raise an `AttributeError`).

Comment: Oh! My bad!! instead of that you can connect the `clicked` signal of your widget, it will give you event from which you can get the position of click

Answer (score 0):

You can override `mousePressEvent`:

1. Get current coordinate of mouse
2. Compared with coordinates of labels
3. Change the style if mouse hovers on a label

```
Class sample(QWidget):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        mouse_coordinate = event.globalPos()
        cliked_label = find_clicked_label(mouse_coordinate)
        if cliked_label:
            cliked_label.setStyleSheet(YOUR_STYLE)

    def find_clicked_label(mouse_coordinate):
        '''
        if find a label:
            return this label
        '''
```